# Grid Will Not Expand to Fill In White Space

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to build a better responsive page though I am struggling with two grids.

I need the tiles that state different food to expand when the page expands vertically and for the bottom green tiles to stay at the bottom, so far they keep jumping up to the top of the page and I can not figure out why.

The image below shows the issues I've been having.

[image: Screenshot of grid issues]

The code below shows intro into the CSS page

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  }
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px [nav-start] auto 125px [nav-end];
  grid-template-columns:  [header-start] minmax(200px, 2fr) 10fr [header-end];
  grid-template-areas: "header  header"
                      "nav    content"
                      "nav    footer";
  }

header {
  grid-column: header-start / header-end;
  background-color: navy;
}
nav {
  grid-row: nav-start / nav-end;
  background-color: slategrey;
}

content {
    background-color: white;
}


footer {
    background-color: #726a6a;
}
.container {
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5px 5px;
  padding: 5px;

}
.cell {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
    line-height: 25px;
.cell-1 {
  background: brown;
}
.cell-2 {
  background: brown;
}
.cell-3 {
  background: brown;
}
.cell-4 {
  background: black;
}
.cell-5 {
  background: black;
}
.cell-6 {
  background: black;
}
.cell-7 {
  background: orange;
}
.cell-8 {
  background: orange;
}
.cell-9 {
  background: orange;
}
.cell-10 {
  background: maroon;
}
.cell-11 {
  background: maroon;
}
.cell-12 {
  background: maroon;
}
.cell-13 {
  background: lightblue;
}
.cell-14 {
  background: lightblue;
}
.cell-15 {
  background: lightblue;
}
.cell-16 {
  background: tan;
}
.cell-17 {
  background: tan;
}
.cell-18 {
  background: tan;
}
.cell-19 {
  background: green;
}
.cell-20 {
  background: green;
}
.cell-21 {
  background: green;
}
.cell-22 {
  background: gold;
}
.cell-23 {
  background: gold;
}
.cell-24 {
  background: gold;
}
.cell-25 {
  background: coral;
}
.cell-26 {
  background: coral;
}
.cell-27 {
  background: coral;

}
.cell-28 {
  background: maroon;
}
.cell-29 {
  background: maroon;
}
.cell-30 {
  background: maroon;
}
.cell-31 {
  background: blueviolet;
}
.cell-32 {
  background: blueviolet;
}
.cell-33 {
  background: blueviolet;
}
.cell-34 {
  background: navy;
}
.cell-35 {
  background: navy;
}
.cell-36 {
  background: darkgreen;
}
```

The next bit of code shows the condiments/add on's (lettuce, tomato, onion, etc.) This is the portion that jumps near the top.

```
.container2 {
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 5px 4px;
  padding: 5px;

}
.cellb {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  padding: .5rem;

    }
.cell-1a {
  background: teal;
}
.cell-2a {
  background: teal;
}
.cell-3a {
  background: teal;
}
.cell-4a {
  background: teal;
}
.cell-5a {
  background: teal;
}
.cell-6a {
  background: teal;
}
.cell-7a {
  background: teal;
}
.cell-8a {
  background: teal;
}
.cell-9a {
  background: teal;
}
.cell-10a {
    background: teal;
}
```

Am I on the right track thinking that I need to play with the grid-template-rows dimension or is it something else?

Comment: `grid-template-rows: ??` What have you tried?

Comment: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(auto-fill)) 20%; 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr; I've played around with different grid template-rows but can seem to find the correct one

Comment: As mentioned in a previous comment, you should post enough code to reproduce the problem. We would be able to help you more effectively that way.

Comment: Okay thank you, I thought I had too much.